# Help understanding sequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Prove $(1 + z + z^{2} + \ldots + z^{9})
\cdot (1 + z^{10} + z^{20} + \ldots + z^{90})
\cdot (1 + z^{100} + z^{200} + \ldots + z^{900})
\cdot \ldots = \frac{1}{1 - z}$.

For $|z|<1$.

De Souza and Silva give the following proof in the book Berkeley Problems in Mathematics:

[image]

But I don't understand how they got there. It seems to me several steps are missing.

Comment: Each factor is a geometric progression.

Comment: $\displaystyle (1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n)(1-r) = \left(1 - r^{n+1}\right).$  Therefore, $\displaystyle (1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n) = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$

Comment: Note, if you interpret this in terms of generating functions this is equivalent to saying that each positive integer has a unique base-10 expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require {cancel} $

You can verify for yourself that for any $w \in \mathbb C$ then $(1-w)(1 + w + w^2 + ..... + w^{n-1}) = 1-w^n$.

So if $w \ne 1$ then $\frac {1-w^n}{1-w}= (1 + w+w^2 + ... + w^{n-1})$ and if $w = z^{k}$ then $(1 + z^k + z^{2k} + .... + z^{mk}) = \frac {1 - z^{(m+1)k}}{1-z^k}$

And so every $1 + z^{10^k} + z^{2\times 10^k} + .... + z^{9\times 10^k}=\frac {1-z^{10^{k+1}}}{1- z^{10^k}}$

This is a very well known result and the text assumes the reader should have seen that result (or something very similar to it) many many times before.

So

$(1 + z + z^{2} + \ldots + z^{9})
\cdot (1 + z^{10} + z^{20} + \ldots + z^{90})
\cdot (1 + z^{100} + z^{200} + \ldots + z^{900})
\cdot \ldots (1 + z^{10^k} + z^{2\times 10^k} + .... + z^{9\times 10^k})=$

$\frac {1 - z^{10}}{1 - z}\cdot \frac {1- z^{100}}{1-z^{10}} \cdot \frac {1-z^{100}}{1-z^{100}} \cdot .... \cdot\frac{1 + z^{10^{k+1}}}{1-z^{10^k}}=$

$\frac {\cancel{1 - z^{10}}}{1 - z}\cdot \frac {\cancel{1- z^{100}}}{\cancel{1-z^{10}}} \cdot \frac {\cancel{1-z^{100}}}{\cancel{1-z^{100}}} \cdot .... \cdot\frac{1 + z^{10^{k+1}}}{\cancel{1-z^{10^k}}}=$

$\frac {1+z^{k+1}}{1-z}$

Now if (and only if) $|z| < 1$ then $\lim_{k\to \infty} z^{k+1} = 0$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac {1 - z^{10^{k+1}}}{1-z} =\frac 1{1-z}$.

And so if $|z| < 1$ then

$\lim_{k\to \infty} (1 + z + z^{2} + \ldots + z^{9})
\cdot (1 + z^{10} + z^{20} + \ldots + z^{90})
\cdot (1 + z^{100} + z^{200} + \ldots + z^{900})
\cdot \ldots (1 + z^{10^k} + z^{2\times 10^k} + .... + z^{9\times 10^k})= $

$\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac {1-z^{10^{k+1}}}{1-z} = \frac 1{1-z}$

And as this does converge we may so

$(1 + z + z^{2} + \ldots + z^{9})
\cdot (1 + z^{10} + z^{20} + \ldots + z^{90})
\cdot (1 + z^{100} + z^{200} + \ldots + z^{900})
\cdot \ldots (1 + z^{10^k} + z^{2\times 10^k} + .... =$ (which is an infinite product)

$\lim_{k\to \infty} (1 + z + z^{2} + \ldots + z^{9})
\cdot (1 + z^{10} + z^{20} + \ldots + z^{90})
\cdot (1 + z^{100} + z^{200} + \ldots + z^{900})
\cdot \ldots (1 + z^{10^k} + z^{2\times 10^k} + .... + z^{9\times 10^k})$

which we just saw was $\frac 1{1-z}$.

But this requires that $|z| < 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^9z^{10^ij}\right)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{z^{10^{i+1}}-1}{z^{10^i}-1}\right)=\frac{z^{10^n}-1}{z-1},$$
wich goes to $-1/(z-1)=1/(1-z)$ as $n\to \infty$.

In the first step we've used that
$$
(z^{10^i}-1)\left(1+z^{10^i}+\cdots+z^{9\cdot 10^i}\right) = z^{10^{i+1}}-1,
$$
whence $\sum_{j=0}^9z^{10^i\cdot j}=\frac{z^{10^{i+1}}}{z^{10^i}-1}$, and in the second step, we've used that
$$
\frac{z^{10}-1}{z-1}\cdot \frac{z^{100}-1}{z^{10}-1}\cdots \frac{z^{10^n}-1}{z^{10^{n-1}}-1} = \frac{z^{10^n}-1}{z-1},
$$
because most factors cancel.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, any integer $m$ has a unique representation in base 10: $m=a_0+a_1\cdot 10+a_2\cdot 10^2+\cdots$. For example $103=3+\cdot 10^0+1\cdot 10^2$, which in exponents would look like $z^{103}=z^{3\cdot 1}\cdot z^{0\cdot 10}\cdot z^{1\cdot 100}$

Convince yourself then that every integer power of $z$ occurs exactly once the infinite product, once expanded. You can formally prove this by expanding a finite product that has sufficiently many terms for a given $z^m$.